# Prevent auto-selection in Windows Phone 8 textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using a read-only `TextBox` in my Windows Phone app to display copyable text. Now I would like taps on the `TextBox` a single character, the one on which the user tapped.

The following code properly selects the first character, but a split second later the selection is reset (that is, Windows Phone automatically selects the entire word at the tap location):

```
private void TextBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
    TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { box.Select(0, 1); });
    //simplified example: select only the first character.
}
```

This works fine in WP7, though.
Any ideas on how to revert to the old behaviour?

Comment: On the eventargs, have you tried setting handled to true?

Comment: @ofstream: Yes, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would interact with the rest of the code you've got, but you should be able to use a combination of `SelectionChanged` and `GotFocus` events on the `TextBox` to replace the previous use of the `Tap` handler to stop the Selection being reset by the user.

**Update**
That's not appropriate for this scenario.

From a quick play on my device it looks like some other event like [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is causing this and not Tap. Try moving your code to that event.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I only want to reset the selection when my user taps, not when she modifies the selection by dragging the selection handles, for example.

Comment: But why? Tap selects a word everywhere else on the phone.

Comment: Because it doesn't select words correctly in languages that do not have spaces. If you type 今天天气怎么样？ in a textbox and try to select words, it selects completely random passages. I'm writing a Chinese dictionary, so I'd like to fix this by explicitly selecting word myself when users tap a character.

Comment: Ok answer updated - looks like it isn't Tap which is causing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the MouseLeftButtonUp doesn't seem to fire in Silverlight for WP7 :/

Comment: I've never worked with WP, but if you can detect OS you could just do (in Tap) if(isWP8) return; and the same with WP7 in MouseLeftButtonDown.

Comment: Ah yes I meant ManipulationCompleted :)